# Trying to get the arraylist value inside hashmap key

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm probably being stupid here...but I need help with this one! Basically i need to do a .contains("message") to determine if the key already contains the incoming message.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just as a note, i do not want it to do anything if it already exists! Currently its not adding it to the list.

EDIT2: the date will not matter for the incoming message because the incoming message does not have the date portion.

```
private Map<Integer,List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();        

public synchronized void addToProblemList(String incomingMessage, int storeNumber){
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    if(map.get(storeNumber)==null){
        map.put(storeNumber, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    for(String lookForText : map.get(storeNumber)){
        if(lookForText.contains(incomingMessage)){

        }else if(!lookForText.contains(incomingMessage)){
            map.get(storeNumber).add(incomingMessage+"\nTime of incident: "+formattedDate+"\n--------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

It used to look like this, but it always added it:

```
    public synchronized void addToProblemList(String incomingMessage, int storeNumber){
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    if(map.get(storeNumber)==null){
        map.put(storeNumber, new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    if(map.get(storeNumber).contains(incomingMessage)==true){
    //Do nothing
    }
    if (map.get(storeNumber).contains(incomingMessage)==false){
    map.get(storeNumber).add(incomingMessage+"\nTime of incident: "+formattedDate+"\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering now, and what have your tried?

Comment: Currently its not adding it to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are adding to the list is a key of the store number and an empty array list,

So the first message for the store you add to the list is empty, therefore your for loop will not execute as it has no elements to iterate.

So add this

```
if(map.get(storeNumber)==null){
    ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
    aList.add(incomingMessage+"\nTime of incident: "+formattedDate+"\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    map.put(storeNumber, aList);
}
```

Note `map.get(storeNumber).contains(incomingMessage)==true` you dont need to boolean comparison here as `contains()` returns a boolean.

The reason this original approach of yours wouldn't have worked is doing a `List.contains()` means you are doing an check to see if the list contains an exact matching string which it would not have since when you have added the String it also contained `"\nTime of incident: "+formattedDate+"\n...` which I suspect would not have matched just `incomingMessage`

Comment: Let me give that a go; and no the date will not matter for the incoming message because the icoming message does not have the date portion.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
for(String lookForText : map.get(storeNumber)){
if(lookForText.contains(incomingMessage)){
}else if(!lookForText.contains(incomingMessage)){
map.get(storeNumber).add(incomingMessage+"\nTime of incident: "+formattedDate+"\n--------------------------------------------------------");
}
}
```

Try this instead:

```
List<String> messages = map.get(storeNumber);
if(!messages.contains(incomingMessage)){
    map.get(storeNumber).add(incomingMessage+"\nTime of incident: "+formattedDate+"\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    }
```